# AWS: Can't Bundle AMI

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am trying to create an AMIBundle [following these instructions](http://support.rightscale.com/12-Guides/Dashboard_Users_Guide/Clouds/AWS_Global/Image_Locator/Actions/Register_an_AMI#Upload_your_AWS.c2.a0key_and_certificate), but am running into an error. When I get to

> ec2-bundle-vol -d /mnt -k /mnt/pk-XXX.pem -c /mnt/cert-YYY.pem -u 123456789012 -r i386 -p 
>   rightscale_ami

and run it (using my correct variables, of course) I get: `ERROR: You need to be root to run /vol/downloads/ec2-ami-tools-1.3-66634//lib/ec2/amitools/bundlevol.rb`

I am not sure what the problem is. I tried changing the permissions around, but to no avail. 
I am running Ubuntu 11.04 Server on a large instance, have installed the ec2 AMI and ec2 API tools, added them to path and their respective environment variables, and have done `sudo aptitude install ruby`. Maybe I need something else with ruby?  Please help! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up installing the ami and api tools from the multiverse package within Ubuntu's apt manager. When I installed the tools this way, I could correctly do a `sudo` to run as root, whereas when I ran it originally it looked like the super user couldn't get access to my environment variables.